# Getting the Nmea sentence from google fused provider

Tags: android, geolocation, nmea, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'd like to get the NMEA sentence using the android fused location Provider Client, but I can't find any documentation.
Is it possible?
thx

Comment: There might not be a NMEA sentence, as the location might not be determined by GPS. AFAIK, if you want GPS-specific data, you have to work with `LocationManager`.

Comment: sry, I missed your reply. Indeed I used location and works like a charm.